# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS does not load Internal SATA DVD

Tags: gnome, 22.04, udev, sata

I'm running a 64-bit Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS running GNOME 42.9. I have a SATA Hard drive which loads correctly, I also have a SATA DVD Drive but it does not load at all. I have swapped SATA slots and cables.  The hard drive gets recognized with all slots and cables, but the DVD Drive does not.  I have tried two different DVD Drives and same situation with both.

I'm sure the DVD Drives, SATA Cables, and SATA Slots are good.  So I'm not sure what to do next.  I did run sudo lshw, which spit out a lot and not sure what it all means.  Here it is.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ww4868HDtx/

I would appreciate any ideas anyone may have of what I should do next.

Chris

Comment: Are you shutting down the PC between port/cable slots? If you are hot-swapping then you could issue a `sudo dmesg -w` before connecting the DVD drive to see what the system is seeing/reporting (if anything) which may give some clues?